# Why couldn't CMake set COMMON_LANGUAGE_RUNTIME up successfully

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmake, clr

I have a shared library written in C++, and I would like to call it from C#. After some investigation, I decided to use C++/CLI to achieve this goal. However, setting Common Language Runtime Support with CMake, isn't working.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CLR_HEADERS
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/clr/Refer.h
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/clr/Wrapper.h)

add_library(CLR_COM SHARED ${CLR_HEADERS})

target_include_directories(CLR_COM
    PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include
            ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/clr)

set_target_properties(CLR_COM
    PROPERTIES COMMON_LANGUAGE_RUNTIME            ""
               VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES               "System"
               VS_DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK_VERSION "v4.6")
```

Although `VS_DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK_VERSION` is setted successfully, the `COMMON_LANGUAGE_RUNTIME` is still invalid.

[The generated properties of the visual studio project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbdos.png)

Comment: Did you install the "C++/CLI support" component when installing Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, I installed it

Comment: @Nowayout same problem here, did you find a solution eventually?

Comment: @rickyviking Sorry, but I haven't found a solution.

Comment: This might be related: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22054